# Extracting substring in bash script

Tags: regex, bash

I am not that good at bash scripting. I have a requirement to extract a substring between two words of a string. I tried different ways. Could some one help me pls?

This is my text **"RegionName": "eu-west-1", "LatestAmiId": "ami-0ebfeadd9ccacfbb2",**

Remember the the quotes and comma are the part of String. I need to extract the AMI ID alone, Means text between **"LatestAmiId": "** and **",**

Any help pls?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: This looks like a section of JSON, have you considered using a tool like [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to work with JSON objects in scripts? It could prove to be much easier than specifically grabbing a substring

Comment: `awk -F'"' '{print $8}' input_file`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have this string stored in a variable name `input_text` you can get the AmiId using sed like this

```
ami_id=$(echo "$input_text" | sed -e 's/.*LatestAmiId": "//' -e 's/",$//')
```

this uses two different sed scripts:

- `s/.*LatestAmiId": "//` replaces all text up to and including `LatestAmiId": "` with nothing
- `s/",$//` replaces the `",` at the end of the line with nothing

---

As I mentioned in comments, [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) is a tool that I have found really helpful when working with JSON objects in bash scripts. Since your input string looks like a section out of a json response from an AWS api, I highly recommend using a json tool rather than a regex to extract this information.

Comment: Okay. Thanks Will .

Comment: I will try jq. Meanwhile the regex not replacing the first part of string . After the replacement I get "RegionName": "eu-west-1 ami-0ebfeadd9ccacfbb2 . I just needed the ami id

Comment: hmmm, it worked for me as expected, replaced the entire thing. Is it possible that there are newline characters in your string?

Comment: PCRE `.` matches everything except newlines by default

Comment: No there is no new line char. It not replacing "RegionName": "eu-west-1 .

Comment: If you use `'s/.*/foo/'` as the sed script, what is the output?